# The sprite doesnt seems to be jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

i am following a brackeys tutorial, the sprite is moving left right but not jumping. "Jump" is working fine but the results are not present in the gameview.it references a script provided by brackeys but i dont whether thats the problem.
Here is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player_movemnt : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController2D controller; 
   float horizontal_movement =0f;
   public float run_speed = 60f;
    bool jump = false;
    
    void Update()
    {
     horizontal_movement  = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")*run_speed;
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
           Debug.Log("l");
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //move character
    controller.Move(horizontal_movement*Time.fixedDeltaTime,false, jump);
            jump= false;
            
    }           
    }
```

here is the CharacterControl2D scrip

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                          // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
[Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;          // Amount of maxSpeed applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%
[Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;  // How much to smooth out the movement
[SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = false;                         // Whether or not a player can steer while jumping;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                          // A mask determining what is ground to the character
[SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;                           // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
[SerializeField] private Transform m_CeilingCheck;                          // A position marking where to check for ceilings
[SerializeField] private Collider2D m_CrouchDisableCollider;                // A collider that will be disabled when crouching

```
const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
private bool m_Grounded;            // Whether or not the player is grounded.
const float k_CeilingRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can stand up
private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.
private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;

[Header("Events")]
[Space]

public UnityEvent OnLandEvent;

[System.Serializable]
public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }

public BoolEvent OnCrouchEvent;
private bool m_wasCrouching = false;

private void Awake()
{
    m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    if (OnLandEvent == null)
        OnLandEvent = new UnityEvent();

    if (OnCrouchEvent == null)
        OnCrouchEvent = new BoolEvent();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    bool wasGrounded = m_Grounded;
    m_Grounded = false;

    // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
    // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
    for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
    {
        if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
        {
            m_Grounded = true;
            if (!wasGrounded)
                OnLandEvent.Invoke();
        }
    }
}


public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
{
    // If crouching, check to see if the character can stand up
    if (!crouch)
    {
        // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
        if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
        {
            crouch = true;
        }
    }

    //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
    if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
    {

        // If crouching
        if (crouch)
        {
            if (!m_wasCrouching)
            {
                m_wasCrouching = true;
                OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(true);
            }

            // Reduce the speed by the crouchSpeed multiplier
            move *= m_CrouchSpeed;

            // Disable one of the colliders when crouching
            if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = false;
        } else
        {
            // Enable the collider when not crouching
            if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = true;

            if (m_wasCrouching)
            {
                m_wasCrouching = false;
                OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(false);
            }
        }

        // Move the character by finding the target velocity
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
        m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);

        // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
        if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
        {
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        }
        // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
        else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
        {
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        }
    }
    // If the player should jump...
    if (m_Grounded && jump)
    {
        // Add a vertical force to the player.
        m_Grounded = false;
        m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
    }
}


private void Flip()
{
    // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
    m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

    // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

}

i am completely dumbfounded with this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a [separate class](https://github.com/Brackeys/2D-Character-Controller/blob/master/CharacterController2D.cs) to handle your movement, it's always ideal to include it alongside your question. So others wont have to search for it.

Your code appears *okay*, at least based on the tutorial you've mentioned. Double-check that the`m_GroundCheck` GameObject of `CharacterController2D` is on the ground rather than on the bottom of the player, as that's responsible for ensuring you can jump in the first place.

```cs
public CharacterController2D characterController;
public float runSpeed = 60f;

private float _horizontalMovement;
private bool _jump;

private void Update()
{
    _horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        _jump = true;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    characterController.Move(_horizontalMovement * Time.fixedDeltaTime, false, _jump);
    _jump = false;
}
```

I'd recommend working backwards and ensuring your `CharacterController2D` is set up correctly to support the jump, including any attributes you need to add in the inspector window. Such as a reference to GroundCheck and its LayerMask.

[image: Inspector Preview]